# dealing with "<NA>" of date-time object (POSIXct) in R

Tags: r, datetime, na

I have a df as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(
      
     value = c(1,2,3,4), 

     date_time = c(2016-11-15 13:30:00, 2016-11-15 14:30:00, <NA>, 2016-11-15 16:30:00)
                   
                     )
```

in my df, the variable date_time is a POSIXct object that was originally a character object that was transformed to POSIXct object using as_datetime of lubridate package.

I am trying to make anew variable called date_time_new where I replace the `<NA>` in the date_time column with the lag of date_time plus 1:00:00 (add one hour to the previous time and replace the `<NA>` with that).

What I expected is as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(
   
     value = c(1,2,3,4), 

     date_time = c(2016-11-15 13:30:00, 2016-11-15 14:30:00, <NA>, 2016-11-15 16:30:00),
     
     date_time_new = c(2016-11-15 13:30:00, 2016-11-15 14:30:00, 2016-11-15 15:30:00, 2016-11-15 16:30:00)
                     )
```

However, I get the following:

```
df <- data.frame(
      
     value = c(1,2,3,4), 

     date_time = c(2016-11-15 13:30:00, 2016-11-15 14:30:00, <NA>, 2016-11-15 16:30:00),
     
     date_time_new = c(2016-11-15 13:30:00, 2016-11-15 14:30:00, <NA>, 2016-11-15 16:30:00)

                   
                     )
```

And this the code I write:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(date_time_new = ifelse(is.na(date_time) == TRUE, date_time+hms(0,0,1), date_time)
```

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Typo: `= TRUE` with just one `=`. However, you never need to compare `condition == TRUE`, the condition already is `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Comment: And please post the data correctly, the datetimes should be between quotes.

Comment: Thanks Rui, I fixed the typo, however, when I use date_time == "NA"  get error.

Comment: You must use `is.na(date_time)`, just remove the comparison `== TRUE`.

Comment: Thanks, however, the problem still does not go away and I get <NA> in the new column

Comment: Because you are adding `NA` with `hms(0,0,1)`, try adding `lag(date_time) + hms("1 0 0")`.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, it now works.